# How to prove `¬ (A ↔ ¬ A)`

Tags: lean

```
section
open classical
example : ¬ (A ↔ ¬ A) :=
have hn : (A ∨ ¬ A), from sorry,
  assume h : (A ↔ ¬ A),
  show false, from or.elim hn
    (assume h1 : A, h.mp h1 h1)
    (assume h2 : ¬ A, h2 (h.mpr h2))
end
```

I am studying Lean with Jeremy Avigad's book *Logic and Proof*. The problem is that I have to deal with Laws of Excluded Middle only with `by_contradiction` tactic. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Perhaps surprisingly, you can solve this one without assuming LEM at all! But it's quite a tricky one to solve constructively. It's the "canonical tricky simple-looking constructive maths problem" in fact, so I'm not too sure about leaving the solution lying around on SO :-) There is a thread about this question on the Lean Zulip.

Comment: @KevinBuzzard Thanks! I didn't know there was a Lean Zulip chat.

By the way, I love your natural number game!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Prove that `A → ¬ A` implies `¬ A`.

**Solution:**

> 1. `A → ¬ A` is equivalent to `A → (A → False)` (by definition)
>
>    ... which is equivalent to `A → False` ([contraction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_rule#Common_structural_rules))
>
>    ... which is `¬ A`

> With this in hand:
>
> 1. Assume `A ↔ ¬ A`
>
>    Weaken this to `A → ¬ A`
>
>    With the insight above, this implies `¬ A`
>
>    Feed that back to (1) to get `A`
>
>    Both `¬ A` and `A` are true. Contradiction.

**Final code:**

> ```
> example : ¬ (A ↔ ¬ A) :=
>   fun h =>
>     have : ¬ A := fun a => h.mp a a
>     have : A   := h.mpr ‹¬ A›
>     by contradiction
> ```

**Cheating:**

> Of course, in a real world project, not a homework problem, we'd just use the [library version](https://leanprover-community.github.io/mathlib4_docs/Std/Logic.html#iff_not_self):
>
> ```
> example : ¬ (A ↔ ¬ A) := by exact?  -- Try this: exact iff_not_self
> ```